# Scala: How to apply the pattern matching function to a csv file which contains the below mentioned values

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions

```
def matchcase(x:String):Int =  x match{
        case "Iris-setosa" => 10
        case "Iris-virginica" => 20
        case "Iris-versicolor"=> 30
        case _ => 0
```

The sample data in the csv file is as below:

```
1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
51,7,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
52,6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
53,6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
103,7.1,3,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica
104,6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
105,6.5,3,5.8,2.2,Iris-virginica
```

Comment: your pattern matching code looks good. whats the problem?

Comment: Actually i want to replace the text in the whole file by using the matchcase function.Can we do this.Please suggest some idea.If the value go into a new field(column) also good.

Comment: I have tried answering. :) Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you've mentioned

> Actually i want to replace the text in the whole file by using the matchcase function

And assuming that you have data and function as mentioned in the question, you can use `scala.io.Source.fromFile` to read the file

```
val data = scala.io.Source.fromFile("input file path")
```

call the `matchcase` function you have written

```
val replacedData = data.getLines().map(_.split(",")).map(array => array.init.mkString(",")+","+matchcase(array.last))
```

and finally write the output

```
new PrintWriter("path to output file"){write(replacedData.mkString("\n")); close}
```

You should have a file with following data

```
1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,10
2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2,10
3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,10
51,7,3.2,4.7,1.4,30
52,6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,30
53,6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,30
103,7.1,3,5.9,2.1,20
104,6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,20
105,6.5,3,5.8,2.2,20
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: This is what i expected output. Thanks  a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use extractor pattern in Scala with regex

Given regex

```
val regex = "[[0-9]|,|\\.]+([[a-zA-z]|\\-]+)".r
```

Now Just pattern match the whole text line by line

```
lines.map {
  case regex(name) => Some(name)
  case _ => None
}
```

later use your `matchCase` function to convert strings (names) into numbers
and replace the name with number

#### Code you looking for

```
lines.map { line =>
  line match {
   case regex(name) => line.replace("[[a-zA-z]|\\-]+", matchcase(name).toString)
   case _ => line
  }
}
```

## Scala REPL

```
scala> val regex = "[[0-9]|,|\\.]+([[a-zA-z]|\\-]+)".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = [[0-9]|,|\.]+([[a-zA-z]|\-]+)

scala> "1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa" match { case regex(str) => println(s"name: $str")}
name: Iris-setosa
```

Next

Processing whole text

```
scala> val text = """
     | 1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
     | 2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
     | 3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
     | 51,7,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
     | 52,6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
     | 53,6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
     | 103,7.1,3,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica
     | 104,6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
     | 105,6.5,3,5.8,2.2,Iris-virginica
     | """.stripMargin
text: String =
"
1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
51,7,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
52,6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
53,6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
103,7.1,3,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica
104,6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
105,6.5,3,5.8,2.2,Iris-virginica
"

scala> val lines = text.split("\n").filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)
lines: Array[String] = Array(1,5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa, 2,4.9,3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa, 3,4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa, 51,7,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor, 52,6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor, 53,6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor, 103,7.1,3,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica, 104,6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica, 105,6.5,3,5.8,2.2,Iris-virginica)

scala> lines.map {
     |  case regex(name) => Some(name)
     |  case _ => None
     | }
res18: Array[Option[String]] = Array(Some(Iris-setosa), Some(Iris-setosa), Some(Iris-setosa), Some(Iris-versicolor), Some(Iris-versicolor), Some(Iris-versicolor), Some(Iris-virginica), Some(Iris-virginica), Some(Iris-virginica))
```

Now use `collect` and only collect values which are `Some`

```
scala> res18.collect { case Some(value) => value }
res19: Array[String] = Array(Iris-setosa, Iris-setosa, Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor, Iris-versicolor, Iris-versicolor, Iris-virginica, Iris-virginica, Iris-virginica)

scala> res19.mkString("\n")
res20: String =
Iris-setosa
Iris-setosa
Iris-setosa
Iris-versicolor
Iris-versicolor
Iris-versicolor
Iris-virginica
Iris-virginica
Iris-virginica
```